Show/Hide Plotly Heatmap Traces via a Dropdown with External JS
I would like to make a plot that has 15 different heatmap traces and then show/hide them via external javascript, or built-in plotly functionality. I don’t think that visible=‘legendonly’ will work because then I’ll have 15 legends on screen..
Thank you in advance!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
